# Provide instance on condition no other module provides that instance yet

Tags: java, guice

My application uses Guice for Dependency Injection and consists of several modules, some depend on an instance of class X and some need to be able to run independently of the main application.
So in the MainModule I have to provide an instance of class X, while some sub-modules also need to provide that instance, since their respective applications need to be able to run without the MainModule providing said instance of class X. Which leads to errors because "an instance of class X was already bound".

I have been looking around for a while now, but mostly I find references to PrivateModules which don't really do what I need, also I found a lot on OptionalBindings which, as far as I understand, mainly provide default values.

What I need is some sort of conditional binding as in "If another module provides an instance of class X do nothing, if no other module provides an instance of class X provide this one."

Answer (score 1):

https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Modules.html

The override methods are probably what you want

Comment: This looks like it requires me to provide an instance of the parent module at runtime, but I don't always know whether the small application has a parent at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

### Isolation

The problem is caused by insufficient isolation of various sub-systems. 
From a sub-system `S` point of view, type `X` has changed its contract over time. In the past, the type gave `S` ability to control all of its instances. But with integrations, control of instances was lost. Type `X` changed its behavior in an incompatible way.

Sub-system `S` should have been more isolated. It should not have used types that are potentially in conflict with other systems. It should have used its own private types instead, there'd be no issue then.

Now let's say in our hypothetical problem, there is a `Database` sub-system. It uses timeout when issuing network calls. It wants an instance of `Timeout` that has the value of 100 millis. `EmailSender` sub-system expects to be slower. Its `Timeout` has to equal 5 seconds. The systems conflict when integrated.

### One approach: private wrapper types

```
    // EmailSender-private wrapper. Class is not public on purpose.
    class EmailSenderTimeout {
      final Timeout timeout;
      EmailSenderTimeout(Timeout t) { this.timeout = t; }
    }

    // In the module
    bind(EmailSenderTimeout.class)
        .toInstance(new EmailSenderTimeout(Timeout.seconds(5));

    // In the service
    @Inject
    EmailSendingService(EmailSenderTimeout timeout) {
      long millis = timeout.timeout.millis();
    }
```

**Walla!** Should anyone ever go and bind `Timeout` to whatever their heart desires, we the `EmailSender` still have our 5 seconds!

We achieved through isolation. We are still sharing the `Timeout` type, but we are no longer sharing instances.

### Guicier: binding annotations

This mechanism is Guice's answer to our exact problem.

```
    // Define this annotation once in the sub-system somewhere.
    // Perhaps even directly in the Module class.
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @BindingAnnotation
    @interface ForEmail { }

    // EmailModule
    protected void configure() {
      bind(Timeout.class).annotatedWith(ForEmail.class)
          .toInstance(Timeout.seconds(5);
    }

    // Service
    class EmailSendingService {
      @Inject
      EmailServiceImpl(@ForEmail Timeout timeout) {
        long millis = timeout.millis();
      }
    }
```

You can reuse the annotation for other shared types, too:

```
    class EmailServiceImpl {
      @Inject
      EmailServiceImpl(@ForEmail Timeout timeout, 
          @ForEmail RemoteAddress remoteAddress, 
          @ForEmail Protocol protocol) {
      }
    }
```

Each sub-system would declare its own private binding annotation and use it throughout.

In absolute, **no two sub-systems should bind the same types**, whether or not they are integrated today.

### Simplistic mental model of Guice

There must never be duplicates in `bindings`:

```
    class Guice {
      HashMap<Key, Provider> bindings;
    }

    // Combines 3 things: Class, Generic Types, and Annotation
    class Key {
      Class<?> actualClass;
      @Nullable Class<?> annotationClass;
      @Nullable Type genericTypes;
    }
```

More details: [Key.java](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/Key.java), [TypeLiteral.java](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.java)

Comment: Let me see if I got you right, you say just bind the desired type in your app overriding the one that exit, if exist? I was thinking of something more like if(Injector. getInstance(X)==null) Modules.override(new ModuleA(){configure(){bind(x)}})

Comment: With annotations, the types don't override each other. It's as if every sub-system is binding its own type. Modules.override() still keeps a single binding globally.

Comment: The pseudo code was only a why to express the idea. Maybe this will make more sense let's assume install was exposed externally.  

Module m1 = new Module(){configure(){bind(y)}})
Module m2 = new Module(){configure(){bind(z)}})

Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(m1,m2)

if (injector.getExistingBinding (X)==null) {
injector =   Guice.createInjector(m1,m2,new Module (){configure(){bind(x)}}))
}

Comment: You could use Builders to create your modules: `install(ModuleX.newBuilder().replaceDefaultImplementation(XInterface, YourImplementation).build()`

Comment: can you add this as an example to the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately on provided a satisfying answer from my point of view so I will not hand the bounty to anyone. Upvoting @iluxa answer as he provided to most significant information

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Module-equality to address this need:

Guice adds each module that you `install` into a `Set`, which has the effect of deduplicating any Modules that are redundantly installed, as long as they considered **`equal`**.

So, you can embed the binding of class X in its own `Module`, and ensure that its module-class has an `equals` method which will identify other instances of the same module as equal.

For example:

```java
class XModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(X.class).to(RealX.class); // whatever you need to deduplicate
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return other == this || (other instanceof XModule);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return XModule.class.hashCode();
  }
}

class ModuleA extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    install(new XModule());
  }
}

class ModuleB extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    install(new ModuleA());
    install(new XModule()); // will be deduplicated
  }
}
```

(this is also discussed here: [Ensure Module Is Loaded Only Once In Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735211/ensure-module-is-loaded-only-once-in-guice))

Comment: Although this is useful I don’t think this solve the original problem.
I would like see something more like springs  \@Conditional or \@ConditionalOnMissingBean